# Strict Topology in multiplier algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

Supose $A$ a $C^*$-algebra. If $\phi: M(A) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a linear functional (where $M(A)$ is the multiplier algebra of $A$) then what does it means that $\phi$ is continuous in the strict topology? If $\phi$ is continuous in the strict topology then it is continuous in the norm of $A$?

Comment: the strict topology on $M(A)$ is defined here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplier_algebra . Maybe one means the following: if $(n_i)$ is a net in $M(A)$ converging to an element $n\in M(A)$, then $\phi(n_i)\to \phi(n)$ in $\mathbb{C}$